# How to update a cache value in table1 by JOINing and SUMing values in a sub-table?

Tags: mysql

I have an orders table:

```
id | name | date | total | balance
```

and an order_payments table:

```
id | order_id | amount | date
```

I'd like to update my Orders table 'balance' column periodically by summing the 'amount' column of order_payments and subtracting from the 'total'. Is there a way to do this with one Update statement by JOINing with order_payments and taking the SUM of 'amount'? Something like:

```
UPDATE orders 
LEFT JOIN order_payments ON order_payments.order_id = orders.id
SET balance = SUM(order_payments.amount)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm more of a MSSQL user, but I'm pretty sure something similar to the following should work in mysql as well. You might have to slightly fidget with the syntax. The general idea is that you can't update a table with aggregate values directly, so you use a derived table to do the aggregation, join to it, and then update.

```
update o
set balance = op.amt
from orders o
left join (select order_id, sum(amount) amt from order_payments group by order_id) op
on o.id = op.order_id
```

Comment: thanks. I also found that you can create a temporary table to store the sum amounts, then run an update with a join on the temp table to cache the sum amounts.  Actually, it seems your solution basically creates the temp table in the same query, so the performance will probably be the same.

Comment: That's correct. I prefer to use derived tables rather than temporary tables if possible, simply because it avoids a bit of overhead and feels cleaner. But logically, they're equivalent.